# how to get nearest element based on specifed height using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an HTML below. I need to insert an image or an iframe in the middle of the parent div using js. My solution is that i will get the hight of this div using height() and then divide it by 2. After that i need to find the closet p tag based on the height and then append the image to that p tag. In this case how can i get the closet p tag base on the height ?

```html
<div id="body-detail" class="body-detail">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the BoundingClientRect of your parent `<div>`, calculate its middle.
2. Get the BoundingClientRect of each `<p>`, calculate its middle.
3. Select the `<p>` with the smallest distance between its middle and the `<div>`'s
4. Append your `<img>` to that `<p>`

Beware to do all that in `window`'s `load` event, so that your `<p>` elements are guaranteed to be already sized, especially if they contain images with no fixed size or are styled in an external stylesheet.

```js
$(window).on('load', _e => {

  //TODO: remove (for tests only)
  //Set random height for p elements
  $('#body-detail p').each((index, p) => p.style.minHeight = (Math.random() * 50 + 20) + "px");

  //Find parent div middle in height
  const bodyDetail = $('#body-detail');
  const bdRect = bodyDetail[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const bdMiddle = bdRect.y + bdRect.height / 2;
  console.log('div middle at', bdMiddle);

  //Find p which middle is the closest to parent div's
  let closestP;
  let closestDist = 1e9;
  bodyDetail.children('p').each((index, p) => {
    const pRect = p.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pMiddle = pRect.y + pRect.height / 2;
    console.log('  p middle at', bdMiddle);
    const dist = Math.abs(pMiddle - bdMiddle);
    if (dist < closestDist) {
      console.log('  closer than', closestDist);
      closestDist = dist;
      closestP = $(p);
    }
  });

  //Exit if none found
  if (!closestP) {
    console.log('No p in', bodyDetail);
    return;
  }

  //Append image
  closestP.append('<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" />');
  closestP.addClass('appended');
});
```

```css
.appended {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body-detail" class="body-detail">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just edited the snippet to use jQuery over plain js